# Changing background onchange on check box: jquery

Tags: jquery

I am new to jquery and i am having problem i want to change background color of parent div when i click at checkbox

Please Advice

Thank You

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function chngbg(id){
        id2 = "d-" + id;
        $(id2).addClass('bg');
    }
</script>

<div class="dataDiv" id="d-<?=$row->id?>">
    <input type="checkbox" onchange="chngbg($(this).val());" value="<?=$row->id?>" name="cbox" /></span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing the `#` in your id selector.

```
function chngbg (id) { 
    id2 = "#d-" + id; 
    $(id2).addClass('bg'); 
}
```

By the way, you've got an extra `</span>` that seems like it doesn't belong.

Answer (score 2):

An id selector needs to have a leading `#` character.

```
var id2 = "#d-" + id;
```

Comment: (Assuming the rest works; you also have a spurious `<span>` tag.) [Fiddle w/o the PHP](http://jsfiddle.net/davelnewton/RyhhY/).

Answer (score 1):

If you are leaning jquery, its better to do such tasks using the following method.

```
$("#yourcheckboxselector").change(function() {
    id = "#d-" + id;
    $(id).addClass('bg');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You'll just need to clean up the layout, i added a lot of comments since you said you were new. This will do what you want though.

```
$(function(){  //all of this will execute on page load

    $("[name='cbox']").click(function(event){ //this will bind to the click handler for your checkbox
        $(this) // this equals the checkbox that was clicked
            .parent() //this traverses up to the parent div
                    .addClass("bg"); //this adds the class

    });

});
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want it to be similar to your example, you could set a php var of $ids to an array, then add the ids to it:

```
<?
    $ids[] = $row->id;
?>
<div class="dataDiv" id="d-<?= $row->id; ?>">
    <input type="checkbox" value="<?= $row->id; ?>" name="cbox" />
</div>
```

Then, in your script, you could do:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('<?= '#' . implode(',#', $ids); ?>').change(function() {
            $(this).closest('div').addClass('bg');
        });
    });
</script>
```

Or if you don't want to use the $ids var you can select via class name (best way) or where name='cbox', or something else.